# copy entire row (without knowing field names)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, identity

Using SQL Server 2008, I would like to duplicate one row of a table, **without knowing the field names**.  My key issue: as the table grows and mutates over time, I would like this copy-script to keep working, without me having to write out 30+ ever-changing fields, ugh.

Also at issue, of course, is **IDENTITY fields cannot be copied**.

My code below *does work*, but I wonder if there's a more appropriate method than my thrown-together text string SQL statement?

So thank you in advance.  Here's my (*yes, working*) code - I welcome suggestions on improving it.
Todd

```
alter procedure spEventCopy
   @EventID int
as
begin

   -- VARS...
   declare @SQL varchar(8000)

   -- LIST ALL FIELDS (*EXCLUDE* IDENTITY FIELDS).
   -- USE [BRACKETS] FOR ANY SILLY FIELD-NAMES WITH SPACES, OR RESERVED WORDS...
   select @SQL = coalesce(@SQL + ', ', '') + '[' + column_name + ']'
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   where TABLE_NAME = 'EventsTable'
     and COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('EventsTable'), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 0

   -- FINISH SQL COPY STATEMENT...
   set @SQL = 'insert into EventsTable '
            + ' select ' + @SQL
            + ' from EventsTable '
            + ' where EventID = ' + ltrim(str(@EventID))

   -- COPY ROW...
   exec(@SQL)

   -- REMEMBER NEW ID...
   set @EventID = @@IDENTITY

   -- (do other stuff here)

   -- DONE...
   -- JUST FOR KICKS, RETURN THE SQL STATEMENT SO I CAN REVIEW IT IF I WISH...
   select EventID = @EventID, SQL = @SQL

end
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't any magic way to say "SELECT all columns except `<foo>`" - the way you're doing it is how you'll have to do it (the hack in the other answer aside).

Here is how I would alter your code, with these changes (some are hyperlinked so you can read my opinion about why):

- [use `sys.columns` over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)
- use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`
- [use `scope_identity` instead of `@@identity`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity)
- [use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)
- use `stuff` instead of `coalesce`
- [use `SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist)
- [add semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- use `QUOTENAME` since it's safer than `'[' + ... + ']'`

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spEventCopy
   @EventID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql += ',' + QUOTENAME(name)
      FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.EventsTable')
      AND is_identity = 0;

    SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '');

    SET @sql = N'INSERT dbo.EventsTable(' + @sql + ')
      SELECT ' + @sql + ' FROM dbo.EventsTable
      WHERE EventID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @EventID) + ';';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SELECT @EventID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- do stuff with the new row here

    SELECT EventID = @EventID, SQL = @SQL;
END
```

Comment: Aaron, that's the "-- (do other stuff here)" line near the bottom.  I obviously don't need two copies of identical data, but whittled down the sample code to its core for the sake of sharing.

Comment: +1 You haven't explicitly called out the use of `QUOTENAME` in your list that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the what your identity column is called (and it won't be the column changing), you could do this:

```
SELECT * INTO #dummy FROM EventsTable where EventID = @EventID;

ALTER TABLE #dummy
DROP COLUMN MyIdentityColumn

INSERT EventsTable SELECT * FROM #dummy
DROP TABLE #dummy
```

Since a table can only every have one identity column, specifying that in the query shouldn't limit you too much.

As Aaron Bertrand points out, there are risks associated with this approach.  Please read the discussion in the comments below.

Comment: This is a workaround, but I have to suggest that it is kind of a hack.

Comment: True, but you must agree that it is much cleaner and easier to follow than the code in the question.  Perhaps it's a hack, but it's a hack that buys you cleaner code with no downside (that I'm aware of, anyway).

Comment: "Easier to follow" is quite subjective, and no I do not agree - I find the dynamic SQL much more intuitive than creating some #dummy copy of the table. And creating an object in tempdb, even if it only contains one row, can cause contention that isn't incurred by reading the metadata. This can be especially true if the table is wide (e.g. LOB columns) and a single row might not necessarily fit onto a single page.

Comment: ...or if tempdb is already a bottleneck, which it often can be.

Comment: Still, you've just got to love the mind behind a hack like that!